# MFC editbox get cursor, In OnInitDialog function

Tags: mfc, editbox

How do I get cursor when dialog is start at OnInitDialog function,

without user to move click it, like as follow pic

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxxsdx8g744uiq6/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%96%202014-02-11%2009.53.37.png)

---

Other problem is, when the editbox already fill with text, how do I select the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OnInitDialog function, I see as follow description,

```
// return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
```

so I define a variable to the editbox, the set focus on it,

then return false in OnInitDialog function.

```
BOOL CInputTestPoint::OnInitDialog()
{
CDialog::OnInitDialog();

// TODO:  在此加入額外的初始化
m_editTestPointName.SetFocus();

//return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
return false;
// EXCEPTION: OCX 屬性頁應傳回 FALSE
}
```

For select whole text method is as follow

```
define CEdit to the edit box and m_editTestPointName.SetSel(0, strTestPointName.GetLength(), true);

((CEdit *)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_INPUT_TP))->SetSel(0, strTestPointName.GetLength(), true);
```